# check that a list contains only elements from a given "permissible" list

Tags: python, list

I half expect to be "duped" on this.  But there doesn't seem such a Pythonic "brain exercise" in SO, or even in other languages.

Say I have a "permissible" list `[ 45, 6, 155, 44 ]` and I submit a list `[ 6, 44, 19, 12 ]` : I'd just like to know an efficient, elegant and altogether beautiful algorithm for getting the result:

```
LEGAL: [ 6, 44 ]
ILLEGAL: [ 19, 12 ]
```

PS am currently using 2.7 but 3.x answers would also be welcome!

Comment: legal = [x for x in a_list if x in permissible ] - ilegal = [x for x in a_list if x not in permissible ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
permissible = [45, 6, 155, 44]
```

To preserve repeated values:

```
legal = []
illegal = []
for item in submission:
    if item in permissible:
        legal.append(item)
    else:
        illegal.append(item)
```

Or if you're working with unique, hashable values:

```
legal = set(submission) & set(permissible)
illegal = set(submission) - set(permissible)
```

Comment: ah yes, indeed... if it's a set (or can be made into one)... which in my particular use case is so.

Comment: Good point about the requirement for the items to be hashable and unique.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
permissible = [ 45, 6, 155, 44 ]
def get_legal(permissible, input):
    legal = [x for x in input if x in permissible]
    illegal = [x for x in input if x not in permissible]
    return legal, illegal
```

Comment: make permissible a set and you will have an 0(n) solution

Comment: This checks each element for membership in `permissible` twice, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain your `legal` values as a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), then convert any list you want to check to a set and make sure it is [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) of `legal`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this solution

```
some_list = [1,2,3,4]
permissible = [1,2]

legal = [x for x in some_list if x in permissible]
ilegal = [x for x in some_list if x not in permissible]
```

Hope this helps!